# Extract last digit of PID of child

Tags: c, linux

"Making sure that every child, before finishing, wait n seconds (where
n is the last digit of the PID of the child)"

Example:

Child PID: 5023 //Last digit = 3
Sleep(3)

How can i extract the last digit from the PID??

Thank you everybody!

Comment: Have you tried something? Do you already have the PID, or are you having trouble getting that in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

`int lastDigit = pid % 10;`

Be careful though, if that last digit is a 0, you'll get problems!

Comment: What is an example problem if last digit is a 0?  sleep(0) looks OK.

Comment: No he will not, `0 % 10` is `0`. `X % 10` always defined, it will give only `0` to `9`.

Answer (score 4):

If the PID is stored in a variable called `x`, then the last digit can be found as `x % 10`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mod 10` to get the value, for example:

```
int a = 123;
printf("%d\n", a % 10)
```

Output:

```
3
```

Of course you will need the pid instead of a.

Answer (score 0):

PID is usually of type pid_t an integer type, from "sys/types.h".  As it should be a *signed* type recommend

unsigned LastDigit = ((unsigned) pid) % 10;

This will insure your mod does not report negative results, as in -57%10 --> -7.

`sleep(t)` takes an `unsigned` parameter.  Should your variable `pid`, take on a negative value like -1, `sleep(pid % 10)`, would sleep for a *long* time.

[Edit] `pid_t` is a signed type.  A `pid_t` variable is negative on error returns from functions such as `fork()`,

Comment: A pid will always be positive as from POSIX specs. That if not referring to a group of processes (which is not the aim of the question).

Comment: @Lucian Enache I am sure you are correct, but specs change.  I am more confident that an `unsigned` will never become negative more than POSIX specs.